# If $f$ is class $C^1$, prove that there exists $M>0$ such that $\forall x,y$ $\Vert Df(x)y\Vert \le M\Vert y\Vert$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and $f : A \to \mathbb R^n$ is class $C^1$, then there exists $M>0$,such that for all $x \in A, y \in \mathbb R^n$

$$\Vert Df(x)y\Vert\le M\Vert y\Vert$$

This is a part of proof of Inverse function theorem that i don't get.

Obiously every linear map on $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded so $$(\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in \mathbb R^n)(\exists M_x>0)(\Vert Df(x)y\Vert \le M_x\Vert y\Vert)$$

However if we look at the $M:= \sup_{x\in A}M_x $, I dont see the argument that $M < \infty$

Edit:
In the original text, i am only looking at $K(0,r) \subseteq A$ where $\det Df(x) \not = 0$

Comment: It is wrong. Take $n=1,A=\mathbb R, f(x)=x$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean there is a neighbourhood of some $x$ such that this is true?

Comment: This is true on a compact subset $A$, but not on a general open $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: how about some open ball around $c \in A$

Comment: If you take an open ball $B$ whose closure lies inside the open set $A$, then $\sup_{x \in \bar{B}} \lVert Df(x)\rVert < \infty$ since $f$ is assumed $C^1$, which means $Df$ is continuous, and hence attains a maximum on the compact ball $\bar{B}$. Since the supremum over the closed ball is finite, the supremum over the open ball is also finite. (but in any case, by shrinking the ball small enough, we can WLOG assume its closure lies inside $A$)

Comment: I think the statement is for the inverse of the differential $Df$ at some point $x$ in the neighbourhood of $0$ and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768080/assume-t-n-t-are-bounded-bijective-linear-operators-t-n-to-t-pointwise-sho) proves $x\mapsto (Df(x))^{-1})$ is continuous on $A$ (as $J_f(x)\ne 0$ implies $Df(x)$ is also surjective as in the thread) and then it has to be bounded on a neighbourhood contained in $A$.