# Assume $T_n,T$ are bounded bijective linear operators $T_n \to T$ pointwise. Show $T_n^{-1}\to T^{-1}$ pointwise $\iff$ $\|T_n^{-1}\|\leq C$

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume $T_n,T$ are bounded bijective linear operators $X \to Y$ and $T_n \to T$ pointwise. Show $T_n^{-1}\to T^{-1}$ pointwise $\iff$ $\|T_n^{-1}\|\leq C$

Note: $X,Y$ are banach spaces.

My proof:

Forward direction is uniform boundedness principle. Backwards:

Let us assume that $T_n^{-1}(y)\not \to T^{-1}(y)$ so there is a subsequence and $y$ s.t $\|T_{n_k}^{-1}(y)- T^{-1}(y)\|\geq \epsilon$. Now we know that $T_{n_k}(x)\to T(x)$ and since $T^{-1}_{n}$ are uniformly boundaed we get that $\|T^{-1}_{n_k}(T_{n_k}(x)-T(x))\|<C\|T_{n_k}(x)-T(x)\|\to 0$ Now just let $x=T^{-1}(y)$ and we arrive at contradiction. Is this correct? It seems roundabout in my opinon and there is probably more direct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly without the contradiction. Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary. Since $\{T_n\}, T$ are assumed to be bijective functions, there exist $T^{-1}(y) = x\in X$. We also have a sequence of vectors $T^{-1}_n(y) = x_n$. You noticed that $T^{-1}_n(T_n(x)) = x$ and $T^{-1}_n(T(x)) = T^{-1}_n(y) = x_n$. Hence
$$\begin{align*}|| T_n^{-1}(y) - T^{-1}(y) || = ||x_n - x ||  &= ||T^{-1}_n(T(x)) - T^{-1}_n(T_n(x)) ||\\
 &= ||T_n^{-1} (T(x) - T_n(x))||\\
&\leq C ||T(x) -T_n(x)||\to 0  \end{align*}$$
Since $T_n\to T$ pointwise.